# glob() returning empty directorypath issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to load all the images from a folder by doing this :

```
<?php
 $dirname = "/../../../properties-frontpage/";
 $images = glob($dirname."*.*");
 foreach($images as $image) {
     echo '<div class="item" style="background-image:url(' . $image  . ')" ></div>';
 }
 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($images);
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```

However, it returns an empty array, it's driving me nuts, Im probably defining the `$dirname` the wrong way but can't figure out how.

Thanks guys

**EDIT 01**

the code is written in an include which is placed in a folder called `includes`
here's my folder structure:

wp-content > themes > AWF > includes

the `properties-frontpage` folder is located in the `wp-content` folder.

the include is included in `front-page.php` in my `AWF` theme folder.

So I need to go three levels out right?

**EDIT 02**
Thanks to Stefan Gehrig's solution I now have these url's being outputted:
`/Users/boriskamp/Documents/Local Websites/MijnAWF/wp-content/themes/AWF/includes/../../../properties-frontpage/12.jpg`

how can I turn those into

`/Users/boriskamp/Documents/Local Websites/MijnAWF/wp-content/properties-frontpage/12.jpg` so they work as an `src` ?

Comment: Where do you execute this script and on which path is the properties-frontpage directory

Comment: You're using an absolute path (`/` at the start of your path makes it absolute, and the `/` is root)..... and you can't go up a folder from root.... so effectively you're pointing to `/properties-frontpage/` on your filesystem..... did you mean to use a relative path? Without knowing more about your folder structure, it's difficult to advise you better

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I indeed used and absolute path which I shouldn't. however it still does not work, please see my edited question

Answer (score 2):

The relative path must defined relative to the script being executed and not relative to the script that's included. Sometimes that's hard to figure out and I'm no WP expert. Most often it's easier to pivot relative paths on a known absolute path when using included files. There is a `__DIR__` constant that always points to the directory the current file is in.

So you can do something like that

```
$dirname = __DIR__."/../../../properties-frontpage/";
```

That will resolve to something like

```
/<<absolute path>>/wp-content/themes/AWF/includes/../../../properties-frontpage/
```

Regarding **EDIT 02**:

Removing the `..` traversal can be done with [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) (please read the docs on that happens to symlinks and in case the target path does not exist). But making the path accessible through the web server is more complicated. You cannot simply assume that you just need to strip off the `/Users/boriskamp/Documents/Local Websites/` part make the path relative to the document root. Depending on your server configuration (aliases or path mappings for example) this task gets arbitrary complex and goes beyond the scope of the original question. Perhaps there is a WP helper that can do that - that I don't know.

Comment: perfect, we're getting closer! Thanks! please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead :

```
<?php
 $dirname = "../../../properties-frontpage/"; // Remove the first /
 $images = glob($dirname."*.*");
 foreach($images as $image) {
     echo '<div class="item" style="background-image:url(' . $image  . ')" ></div>';
 }
 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($images);
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: not working, please see my edited answer for the folder structure